# update query is not updating record in sql table

Tags: sql, jsp

I am trying to update record in SQL table but not updating record. No errors/exceptions occurred. When I do click on Update button then again same page opens of that respective fileid(primary key). After clicking on Update button, it is not redirecting to filelist.jsp page.

I am referring to [this youtube code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_uLJfwFzkk) to implement it in my program. But it is not working in my code.

Here is my code.

This is filelist.jsp

```
<th class="text-center">Edit Form</th>
...
<td><a href="edit.jsp?fileid=<%=rs.getInt("fileid")%>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
```

This is edit.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String host="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms";
Statement stat = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","");
%>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<%
stat = conn.createStatement();
String fileid=request.getParameter("fileid");
String data = "select * from dmsfiles where fileid = '"+fileid+"'";
rs = stat.executeQuery(data);
while(rs.next()){
%>
<input type="hidden" name="fileid" value="<%=rs.getInt("fileid")%>">
<table width="400px" align="center" border="2">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Z id</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="zid" value='<%=rs.getString("zid")%>'/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value='<%=rs.getString("firstname")%>'/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value='<%=rs.getString("lastname")%>'/>
</td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
<td><label class="hidden">Status</label></td>
<td>
<select name="status" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="<%=rs.getString(22)%>"><%=rs.getString(22)%></option>
<option value="Public">Reserved</option>
<option value="Team">Implemented</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select File</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple"/>
<span> <%=rs.getString("filename")%> </span>
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="updbtn">Update</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<%
  if(request.getParameter("updbtn") != null){
  String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
  String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
  String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
  String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
  String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");

  ...

  String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
  String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
  String file_Name = "";
  String folder_Name = "allfiles";
  String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
  Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

  if(z_id != null && first_Name != null && last_Name != null && mail_i_d != null && d_iv != null && de_pt != null && cost_centercode != null && doc_num != null && doc_Name != null && doc_Type != null && doc_Category != null && doc_classification != null && authorised_by != null && from_date != null && to_date != null && document_level != null && document_general != null && serial_number != null && revision_number != null && iss_uer != null && sta_tus != null && file_Name != null && folder_Name != null && pa_th != null && add_ed_date != null){
                String query = "update dmsfiles set zid=?, firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where fileid='"+fileid+"'";
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.setString(1,z_id);
                stmt.setString(2,first_Name);
                stmt.setString(3,last_Name);
                stmt.setString(4,mail_i_d);
                stmt.setString(5,d_iv);

                ...

                stmt.setString(23,pa_th);
                stmt.setTimestamp(24, add_ed_date);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("./filelistJSP.jsp");


            }
            }
%>
```

Comment: I am performing same operation referring to youtube video. Still not working in my code. Am I getting wrong somewhere please suggest.

Comment: You don’t have any input with `name=updbtn`.So, your `if(request.getParameter("updbtn") != null..` is never true i guess.

Comment: I changed this id="updbtn" ----> name="updbtn". Still not updating.

Comment: @Swati could you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: check what does `request.getParameter("updbtn")` have in it .